# Magento - custom Account/Registration Fields

Tags: php, magento

I followed this tutorial:
http://www.magento.cc/custom-accountregistration-fields.html

to add fields in the registration form of a customer under Magento, I succeed to run the example with a checkbox in the frontend and the backend.

I had at the backend a text field with 0 or 1 as value, but I would like to have also a checkbox as in the frontend.

Anyone know what changes to do for this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that tutorial where it creates the attributes (Register.html) provide the following settings for your checkbox value.

```
$settings = array (
    'type' => 'bool',
    'input' => 'checkbox',
    'is_required'=> 0
);
```

The tutorial suggests a very unconventional method of setting up. In future you might find it easier to follow a tutorial for making a module to do it, it's a little longer but much more reliable. Or try a [module creator](http://www.magentocommerce.com/extension/1108/modulecreator) to do the groundwork for you.

Comment: Thanks, I'll start to build my own module soon;)

Comment: That was a fast response! Good luck.

Comment: I have now my checkbox in place, but the status is always  "is_required" in database, and I cannot let it leer in backend, in spite of I have precised : 'is_required'=> 0

Comment: This is familiar sounding, I think there was a typo in the original source and `is_required` should be `is_require`.

Comment: always the same thing with "is_require" :(

Comment: any idea for this problem ?? :(

Comment: In the tutorial, for "Setup.php", it uses `required` without the `is_`. (I'm just making guesses at this point)

Comment: I have verified that, I have done like it, but always it makes mein field "is_required =1" in database ! Strange !